# What do I do if I've solved a problem myself for a question I have a bounty on?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question, and after a couple of days there was no answer, but I really hoped to get help, so I placed a bounty on it.

However, shortly after placing the bounty, I stumbled across what seems to be the solution. I was experimenting in a largely aimless and random fashion, and despite expectations, got a positive result.

I'm waiting a bit to be sure about my solution, but if it turns out that it is in fact the answer to my question, what do I do? I know I can answer and accept my own question, but what about the bounty? Do I and can I award it to myself? Is that cool or is that kind of weird?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope.  Once you create a bounty, you lose that rep forever.  I think you used to be able to award it to yourself but it "didn't count", and now it's just the more sensible solution of not letting you award it to yourself at all.

If someone else is able to help or independently discovers the same fix as you, you may want to consider giving them the bounty.  Otherwise just let it expire — if it does without you awarding it, half the rep will go to the highest-scoring answer if it's at +2 or more, if there is such an answer.  (If not, no one gets any.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! It seems a shame for all that rep to just disappear, though, so I hope someone at least tries to put up something helpful, even if it turns out that I've already got the solution.

Comment: I suppose this is to prevent someone from issuing a bounty to encourage answers, only to not award it, correct?

Comment: @Chance I believe so, yes.  You have to be particularly nasty to get a good answer and not reward it if you've already lost the rep, though sadly it has happened at least once that I know of.